# Qual é o sujeito nesta frase?

Tags: gramática, sujeito

No texto seguinte, o sujeito do verbo "criar" são os ativos, ou a emoliência e a hidratação?

> Seus ativos condicionantes, hidratantes e neutralizantes conferem, ainda, emoliência e hidratação, que proporcionam um balanço natural dos cabelos, além de criar um visual maravilhoso.

Eu preciso saber isso pela tradução que estou fazendo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O sujeito são «os ativos»:

> Seus ativos [condicionantes, hidratantes e neutralizantes] conferem ainda emoliência e hidratação (que proporcionam um balanço natural dos cabelos), além de criar um visual maravilhoso.

Diz a frase:

- Que o produto tem ativos condicionantes, hidratantes, e neutralizantes.
- Que esses ativos, além de criar um visual maaaravilhoso, conferem «emoliência» e hidratação.
- E que essa suavidade proporciona um balanço natural dos cabelos.

Parece um produto milagroso!

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta e a explicação. Saudações. :)